# capturing 12-bits raw bayer data using STM32F429 MCU

Tags: stm32f4

The [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/03/b4/b2/36/4c/72/49/29/DM00071990.pdf/files/DM00071990.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00071990.pdf) of the STM32F429 MCU says that the MCU's DCMI supports parallel digital image data with 14-bit bit depth. But at the same time it says that you can capture raw bayer data only in 8-bit. Does it mean you can't take 12-bit raw bayer data from image sensors?
[image]

I'm confused, because the document [AN4658](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/26/22/fe/1d/f1/ca/4c/08/DM00161778.pdf/files/DM00161778.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00161778.pdf) shows that STM32F429's DCMI is capable of taking 8/10, 12, 14 bits progressive video (monochrome or raw bayer). 
[image]

Comment: Hm, can you point out where you think it says 8-bit only? To me it's pretty obvious that it works in all depths.

Comment: @pipe 'It supports 8-bits progressive video monochrome or raw bayer data format'. It doesn't say '12-bit progressive ... not supported', but I assumed it's implied. And then I'm confused. To tell the truth I can't explain how it could be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer from the reference manual of the STM32F429 MCU. 12-bit raw bayer format must be supported. I don't understand why the manufacturer mentions 8-bit format in data sheet..

[image]